# Override the default outgoing call screen

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to override the default outgoing dialer application, and replace it with my activity. I've already got my receiver working and responding properly when an outgoing call is made, but I can't figure out how to prevent the default dialer from displaying and replace it with my custom layout.

When I switch back to my custom application, I can see that it has loaded my dialer layout. It does not take the place of or display on top of the default dialer. Any ideas?

Main activity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace minuteSaver
{
    [Activity (Label = "minuteSaver", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private icCall _receiver;
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            #region Code for using delegate to access class
            var filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall);
            var receiver = new icCall { OnReceiveAction = () => {
                        Toast notifyUser = Toast.MakeText(this, "test", ToastLength.Long);
                    if (filter.GetAction(0) == Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall)
                    {
                        notifyUser.Show();
                        var second = new Intent(this, typeof(mdCall));
                        second.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                        second.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        StartActivity(second);
                    }
                }};
            RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);

            #endregion
            Console.WriteLine ("Receiver registered.");
        }
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Telephony;


namespace minuteSaver
{
    [BroadcastReceiver (Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    class icCall:BroadcastReceiver

    {
        public Action OnReceiveAction;
        public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (OnReceiveAction != null) 
            {
                OnReceiveAction.Invoke ();
                InvokeAbortBroadcast ();
            }
            Toast notifyUser = Toast.MakeText(context, "test", ToastLength.Short);
            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall)
            {
                InvokeAbortBroadcast ();
            Wait (900);
                Intent i = new Intent (context, typeof(mdCall));
                    i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity (i);

                    notifyUser.Show();
                Console.WriteLine ("Debug: Outgoing call detected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try **priority** and **abortBroadcast()**?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Sorry about that, I thought I included my code. I've updated the original post. To answer your question, yes I've tried using priority and abort broadcast.

Comment: what number you set for priority? 1000 or other value?

Comment: This isn't standard Android (Java) code. You must be using some cross-platform tool. You might get better results with your question if you tag it with the name of your cross-platform tool.

Comment: Did you find the solution?? if so kindly post the answer, me also searching for the answer